# Nutch message "No IndexWriters activated" while loading to solr

Tags: solr, nutch

I have run nutch crawler as per nutch tutorial http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial but when i started loading it to solr i am getting this message i.e. "**No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration**"

```
bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr crawl/crawldb/ -dir crawl/segments/
Indexer: starting at 2013-07-15 08:09:13
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
**No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration**

Indexer: finished at 2013-07-15 08:09:21, elapsed: 00:00:07
```

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that the plugin `indexer-solr` is included. Go to the file: `conf/nutch-site.xml` and in the property `plugin.includes` add the plugin, for instance:

> protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)

After adding the plugin the `No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration` warning disappeared in my case.

Check this thread: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/a-plugin-extending-IndexWriter-td4074353.html

Comment: Way late to the party but for anyone else like me who ran into this, make sure to update your nutch-site.xml in the runtime/local/conf/ folder, not just in conf/.

Answer (score 2):

@Tryskele + @Scott101 worked for me:

add plugin.includes property to both /conf/nutch-site.xml and runtime/local/conf/nutch-site.xml files:

```
<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|index-(basic|more)|query-(basic|site|url|lang)|indexer-solr|nutch-extensionpoints|protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(text|html|msexcel|msword|mspowerpoint|pdf)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|metatags)|index-(basic|anchor|more|metadata)</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still an issue, but I was having this problem and then realized that my `src/plugin/build.xml` was missing the `indexer-solr` plugin. Adding the following and then recompiling nutch fixed it for me:

`<ant dir="indexer-solr" target="deploy"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Add the below property in conf/nutch-site.xml for plugin

```
<property>
<name>plugin.includes</name>
<value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|index-(basic|more)|query-(basic|site|url|lang)|indexer-solr|nutch-extensionpoints|protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(text|html|msexcel|msword|mspowerpoint|pdf)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|metatags)|index-(basic|anchor|more|metadata)</value>
</property>
```

Let me know if it solves your problem.