# Can not post to solr during solr and nutch integration

Tags: solr, integration, nutch

I am using solr-4.4.0 and nutch-1.7.
I am newbie in solr and nutch.
I am trying to integrate solr and nutch using following blog::

> http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/building-a-search-engine-with-nutch-and-solr-in-10-minutes/

Started solr successfully::

```
manish@ubuntu:~$ cd /usr/local/solr/example/
manish@ubuntu:/usr/local/solr/example$ java -jar start.jar
```

As well as indexed urls succesfully::

```
manish@ubuntu:/usr/local/nutch/bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 50
```

Sample output::

```
fetching http://www.tatvic.com/tatvic-excel-plugin-webinar (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
-activeThreads=10, spinWaiting=9, fetchQueues.totalSize=36
-activeThreads=10, spinWaiting=10, fetchQueues.totalSize=36
-activeThreads=10, spinWaiting=10, fetchQueues.totalSize=36
-activeThreads=10, spinWaiting=10, fetchQueues.totalSize=36
-activeThreads=10, spinWaiting=10, fetchQueues.totalSize=36
-activeThreads=10, spinWaiting=10, fetchQueues.totalSize=36
.
.
.
.
.
..

Parsed (1ms):http://www.tatvic.com/anomaly-detection/
Parsed (1ms):http://www.tatvic.com/blog/dynamic-funnel-in-google-analytics/
Parsed (1ms):http://www.tatvic.com/blog/google-analytics-custom-reports/
Parsed (0ms):http://www.tatvic.com/collaborative-filtering/
Parsed (1ms):http://www.tatvic.com/contact-thanks/
..
.
.
.
.
LinkDb: linkdb: crawl/linkdb
LinkDb: URL normalize: true
LinkDb: URL filter: true
LinkDb: internal links will be ignored.
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/usr/local/nutch/crawl/segments/20130909064920
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/usr/local/nutch/crawl/segments/20130909065449
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/usr/local/nutch/crawl/segments/20130909064936
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/usr/local/nutch/crawl/segments/20130909043135
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/usr/local/nutch/crawl/segments/20130909035154
LinkDb: merging with existing linkdb: crawl/linkdb
LinkDb: finished at 2013-09-09 07:01:53, elapsed: 00:00:04
crawl finished: crawl
```

But,while posting to solr i got the following::

```
manish@ubuntu:/usr/local/nutch$ bin/nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
Indexer: starting at 2013-09-09 07:05:05
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration

Indexer: finished at 2013-09-09 07:05:12, elapsed: 00:00:07
```

which does it really means???Is it not doing posting at all??

In browser it does not show me anything::

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/select?q=tatvic
```

browser sample::

```
 <response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">111</int><lst name="params"><str name="q">tatvic</str></lst></lst><result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/></response>
```

I tried lot more times!!

I think it might be a issue.

Can you please help me to figure this out??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649567/nutch-message-no-indexwriters-activated-while-loading-to-solr might help

Comment: I already tried it!!If i am doing so then my job would fail..!

Comment: @Jayendra if i do like as you said it throws the following error::

Comment: Follow the link of pastebin::http://pastebin.com/dXMn5Em2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue then i added some property for plugin, it solved my issue.
Check the below link where i answered for the similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25945844/3496666

Answer (score -2):

```
$ bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

SolrIndexer: starting at 2013-09-11 08:23:14
SolrIndexer: finished at 2013-09-11 08:23:28, elapsed: 00:00:13

when i tried this it worked perfectly...

Comment: please explain you answer.