# Solr indexing following a Nutch crawl fails, reports "Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!"

Tags: java, solr, nutch

I have integrated Nutch1.13 with Solr 6.5.1 on an ec2-instance. I did copy schema.xml to Solr using below cp command.I have given localhost as elatic.host in nutch-site.xml in nutch_home/conf folder.

> cp /usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/conf/schema.xml /usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/solr-6.5.1/server/solr/nutch/conf/

Also every time managed-schema is created since it's solr 6. Everything till indexing works fine. The command I tried is

> [ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-137 apache-nutch-1.13]$ bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://35.160.82.191:8983/solr/#/nutch/ urls/ crawl  1

Everything seems fine till indexing while running above command. I'm totally stuck at this last step.

> Error running:
>     /usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=://35.160.82.191:8983/solr/#/nutch/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/20170519074733
>   Failed with exit value 255.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
I changed below prperty in conf/nutch-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>plugin.includes</name>
<value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-html|index-(basic|anchor)|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
</property>
```

Now no error But I get following

> Deduplication finished at 2017-05-19 10:08:05, elapsed: 00:00:03
>   Indexing 20170519100420 to index
>   /usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=//35.160.82.191:8983/solr/nutch/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/20170519100420
>   Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/20170519100420.
>   Indexer: starting at 2017-05-19 10:08:06
>   Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
>   Indexer: URL filtering: false
>   Indexer: URL normalizing: false
>   No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration
>   Indexer: number of documents indexed, deleted, or skipped:
>   Indexer:     44  indexed (add/update)
>   Indexer: finished at 2017-05-19 10:08:10, elapsed: 00:00:03
>   Cleaning up index if possible
>   /usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/bin/nutch clean -Dsolr.server.url=//35.160.82.191:8983/solr/nutch/ crawl/crawldb
>   Fri May 19 10:08:13 UTC 2017 : Finished loop with 1 iterations

**UPDATE 2**
I found adding solr-indexer in nutch-site.xml help as sugested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649567/nutch-message-no-indexwriters-activated-while-loading-to-solr) but now error is in cleaning part

> Error running:
>     /usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/bin/nutch clean -Dsolr.server.url=://35.160.82.191:8983/solr/nutch/ crawl/crawldb
>   Failed with exit value 255.

Any suggestions since I want to implement a search engine using Solr
**UPDATE 3**

Now no error at all. but fetching is not working for some reason. Only urls specified in urls/seed.txt are fetched and crawled. no external links are followed by nutch.

> [ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-137 apache-nutch-1.13]$ bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://35.160.82.191:8983/solr/nutch/ urls/ crawl  5
>   Injecting seed URLs
>   /usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls/
>   Injector: starting at 2017-05-19 12:27:19
>   Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
>   Injector: urlDir: urls
>   Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
>   Injector: overwrite: false
>   Injector: update: false
>   Injector: Total urls rejected by filters: 0
>   Injector: Total urls injected after normalization and filtering: 1
>   Injector: Total urls injected but already in CrawlDb: 1
>   Injector: Total new urls injected: 0
>   Injector: finished at 2017-05-19 12:27:21, elapsed: 00:00:02
>   Fri May 19 12:27:21 UTC 2017 : Iteration 1 of 5
>   Generating a new segment
>   /usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/bin/nutch generate -D mapreduce.job.reduces=2 -D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1000m -D mapreduce.reduce.speculative=false -D mapreduce.map.speculative=false -D mapreduce.map.output.compress=true crawl/crawldb crawl/segments -topN 50000 -numFetchers 1 -noFilter
>   Generator: starting at 2017-05-19 12:27:23
>   Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
>   Generator: filtering: false
>   Generator: normalizing: true
>   Generator: topN: 50000
>   Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...
>   Generate returned 1 (no new segments created)
>   Escaping loop: no more URLs to fetch now

I want to use nutch data for web search results from Solr
**FINAL UPDATE**

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-137 apache-nutch-1.13]$ bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=://35.160.82.191:8983/solr/nutch/ urls/ crawl  1
```

Comment: Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/20170519074733.
Indexer: starting at 2017-05-19 07:52:41
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false

Comment: Active IndexWriters :
ElasticIndexWriter
 elastic.cluster : elastic prefix cluster
 elastic.host : hostname
 elastic.port : port
 elastic.index : elastic index command 
 elastic.max.bulk.docs : elastic bulk index doc counts. (default 250)
 elastic.max.bulk.size : elastic bulk index length in bytes. (default 2500500)
 elastic.exponential.backoff.millis : elastic bulk exponential backoff initial delay in milliseconds. (default 100)
 elastic.exponential.backoff.retries : elastic bulk exponential backoff max retries. (default 10)

Comment: Error running:
  /usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=http://35.160.82.191:8983/solr/#/nutch/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/20170519074733
Failed with exit value 255.

Comment: Cleaning up index if possible
/usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/bin/nutch clean -Dsolr.server.url=://35.160.82.191:8983/solr/nutch/ crawl/crawldb
SolrIndexer: deleting 2/2 documents ERROR CleaningJob: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:865)
 at org.apache.nutch.indexer.CleaningJob.delete(CleaningJob.java:174)
 at org.apache.nutch.indexer.CleaningJob.run(CleaningJob.java:197)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
 at org.apache.nutch.indexer.CleaningJob.main(CleaningJob.java:208)

Answer (score 0):

`nutch-site.xml` doesn't need to be copied over to Solr, only the `schema.xml` file to specify the schema that you want for the data coming from Nutch. If you're using Solr and not ES, then this parameter `elatic.host` is not required. Check the `logs/hadoop.log` file to see if there is more data about the exception, and of course, check the logs on the Solr side, this error usually means that something is wrong with the Solr configuration, missing fields, etc. In this case, since you didn't copy the schema.xml and Nutch is not taking advantage of the managed schema on Solr 6, Solr must be complaining about the missing fields, also your solr URL including the `#` character doesn't look good, that's how the Solr Admin UI shows the data in the browser but to use it from Nutch/terminal should be `/solr/nutch`.

BTW Check [the tutorial](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) although some of the paths have changed in recent Solr versions is still a good guideline on how the integration works

Comment: I had this exception before i added elastic.host "Indexer: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing elastic.cluster and elastic.host. At least one of them should be set in nutch-site.xml "

Comment: and I follow the said tutorial though it's a bit outdated

Comment: Did you have the indexer-elastic plugin enabled in `plugins.include`? That could explain the error about the missing configuration.

Comment: I changed indexer elastic from plugin property. how will I specify solr instead..? now I don't have error but indexing doesn't happen.

Comment: You need to enable the `indexer-solr` plugin in `plugins.include` take a look at this line https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/nutch-default.xml#L1194 to check the default set of plugins, if you don't have any `indexer-*` plugin enabled, then the indexing step is not going to be executed.

Comment: Thanks.. Now there are no exceptions. But I get no results in solr console in the browser.

Comment: I get these in browser query tab after running nutch

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">0</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="indent">on</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
    <str name="_">1495259777131</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0">
</result>
</response>

Comment: what are the changes to be made in /usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/solr-6.5.1/server/solr/nutch/conf/solrconfig.xml  to support nutch's schema.xml rather than managed-schema of solr ?